# OOP good practice in references to the same information in different classes

Tags: oop, swift3

For example I have a class `Person` and `Meetings`

`Meetings` has property `organiser`

```
let organiser : Person
```

Of course I can have the same `Person` organising list of events. What is a good way of storing `Person`.

Of course I can create an array of `Person`s and store the id instead of instance. But it sounds not the best OOP practice.

What is the good way of doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably define the `organiser` or the `Meeting` instance just like you have, and then you'd probably also have a separate array of all of the possible `Person` instances (e.g. it might be a list of employees if talking about some corporate meeting room, it might be a more general list of authorized people if talking about some shared office space).

While a `Person` might have some id number used for other purposes (e.g. maybe some unique number printed on one's physical security badge), the `organiser` would likely just be a reference to the `Person` instance, like you have here, not any identification number or anything like that.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Person{

private Set<Meeting> meetings;
//getters/setters
}

public class Meeting{

private Person person;
//getter/setters
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Swift. It also introduces a strong reference cycle.